# Saving raster data in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, save

I am new to arcpy and I'm trying to write a script to get the raster and check for the minimum cell size value using Get Raster Properties method.

After I run my code I get a message of the minimum value but the raster is not saved. Below are my line of codes:

```py
import arcpy ,os ,sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

input_raster= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_folder,"output.gdb")
outputgdb = output_folder +"\\output.gdb"+ os.sep

output_con_raster = outputgdb + "cond_raster"

inRas1 = arcpy.Raster(input_raster)
rasterValue = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRas1,'MINIMUM')
elevation_min= rasterValue.getOutput(0)
elevation_min.Save(output_con_raster)
```

Is there anything wrong with my code as the save method is not working?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing yourself with the naming convention you are using.

`rasterValue` is a *result* object.

Your next line returns the output of the result object which will be a number, the minimum value in your raster.

Knowing this then the final line `elevation_min.Save(output_con_raster)` make absolutely no sense as your syntax is suggesting you are trying to save a raster when in fact you have nothing more than a number (float or integer).

You could write this value to a table?